# how to multiply integer or double with values in an array?

Tags: c, arrays, math, loops

In a simple way, i have an array of 10 values for example..and i would like to multiply each value with 5. Can i actually just do the following?

```
for (i = 0 ; i <10 ; i++)   
   {
x[i]=x[i]*5;
}
```

And what about getting square for values in the array and be stored back into the same array? As in I want `x[i]=x[i]*x[i]`.

Can I actually just do the multiplication like that?
I tried a couple of combination but it didnt really work..hope someone can help out! Thanks!

Comment: How did you know this did not work? It looks just fine.

Comment: this is actually part of a more complicated program, and it is not returning the results that I want..so i just wanted to ask to make sure..if it is correct then perhaps i should look elsewhere for the prob.. :/

Comment: That works, i[x] *= 5; also works, and i[x] *= x[i]; works for square.

Comment: If you did not get the expected result, the error is not here.  You could have answered your own question simply by inspecting the results.  You are using a source-level debugger right!?

Answer (score 2):

This is perfectly fine.

Comment: what about square root?  Can I do x[i]=sqrt(x[i]*x[i]);    ? With math.h at the top of course..Thanks..

Comment: x[i] = sqrt(x[i]);   otherwise you will get abs(x[i]) ;-)

Comment: hehe actually i wanted to get the absolute value..was just wondering if such multiplication is right. ;) THANKS!

Comment: If you want abs, use the abs function. Or multiply by -1 if needed ;-)

Answer (score 1):

**edited now that the language has been specified**

---

Yes, this "just works" in C.

Can you post more about the errors you're seeing so that we can try to help you out?

Comment: i got it already hehe, actually u guays already answered my doubts :)